Files get served when django website is ran locally, but not when run on heroku
When I run my django website locally all my MEDIA files get served via AWS, but I now uploaded my website to heroku, and it keeps trying to load the files locally instead of AWS, how to fix this?
Settings.py:
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap5"

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap5"

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')


AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'eu-north-1' #change to your region
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())


Hmm, when you're deploying the app is your version of Django different from the version you're using locally? Looking at your file it seems you use Django 4.1 locally (or at least you were using the version when the project was started)? What version does your deployment use?

@AbdulAzizBarkat I have it in my requirement.txt file like this Django==5.1.1 could this be the problem?

The STATICFILES_STORAGE is removed since Django 4.2, use the STORAGES setting instead.
